# Unit Testing Password Validators in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, change-password

I have a CustomPasswordValidator.cs

```
 public class CustomPasswordValidator
{
    public int MinLength { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }


    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(string item)

    {
        IdentityError errors = new IdentityError();
        MinLength = 8;
        MaxLength = 16;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) || item.Length < MinLength || item.Length > MaxLength)

        {

            errors.Description = "password must be of minimum 8 characters ";
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(errors));
        }
        //Minimum eight charachters and maximum 16 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one number and no spaces
        string pattern = @"^(?=.*\d+)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z@#$%^&*-_+={}|:‘,.?`~]{8,16}$";
        //@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,16}";
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern))

        {
            errors.Description = "password must at least have one uppercase letter, one number and no spaces ";
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(errors));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

And a controller which calls the validator class :

```
   public class ValidatePasswordController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordRequest user)
    {
        //get user data 
        string Password = user.Password;
        CustomPasswordValidator CheckPWD = new CustomPasswordValidator();
        var result = CheckPWD.ValidateAsync(Password);
        var errors = result.Result.Errors.ToArray();
        string Description = errors[0].Description;
        return Json(Description);
    }
}
```

I'm new to using  unit testing with TestTools.UnitTesting. I want to create a unit test class that ensures that the right result is being returned. How can I approach that

```
  class PasswordValidatorTest
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPWDValidation()
    {
        var password = "Thi$user12345";
        var w = new ValidatePasswordController() { }; //arrange
        //act


    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-stub-mock-and-fake-in-unit-testing/

Comment: Arrange the subject under test, exercise the member under test and then assert the expected behavior. nothing much to it. You code however could do with some refactoring as it is tightly coupled to implementation concerns. Also your `ChangePassword` methods does not actually change anything. It only validates.

Comment: https://elanderson.net/2016/03/asp-net-core-password-options-and-custom-validators/